# How can I apply offsets to kernel arguments in OpenCL 2.0 with the c++ wrapper

Tags: c++, opencl

In CUDA, I can launch the same kernel to operate concurrently on different sections of the same array by doing calling the code below in a for loop over k:

```
kernel<<<blkPerGrd, thdPerBlk, 0, stream[k]>>>(in_array + offset, out_array + out_offset)
```

I'd like to do the same thing in OpenCL 2.0 with the C++ wrapper. My idea now would be to call the enqueue the kernels on different command queues, set the `in_array` and `out_array` as arguments to the kernel, and pass the offsets as arguments as well. So something like this (in a for loop over k):

```
kernel.setArg(0, in_array);
kernel.setArg(2, in_offset);
kernel.setArg(3, out_array);
kernel.setArg(4, out_offset);
queue[k].enqueueNDRangeKernel(kernel, cl::NullRng, gblRng, lclRange, NULL, NULL);
```

where `in_array` and `out_array` are `cl::Buffer` objects.

Does this make sense or is there a better way to handle offsets? I tried checking if the `cl::Buffer` class accepts pointer arithmetic, but I don't think it does.

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing is an acceptable way to break up a kernel into multiple parts, but there are other ways of doing it.

Personally, I prefer to launch these kinds of kernels by changing the parameters for `enqueueNDRangeKernel`. You might notice that you've conspicuously left one of the parameters "null", or more precisely, `cl::NullRng`. That's normally the Offset parameter, which can be used to do pretty much exactly what you're trying to do.

```
Image img;
std::vector<cl::Event> events;
//Do not perform work on an area larger than 100x100 pixels at a time.
for(int x = 0; x < img.width(); x += 100) {
    int end_x = std::min(img.width(), x + 100);
    for(int y = 0; y < img.height(); y += 100) {
        int end_y = std::min(img.height(), y + 100);
        events.emplace_back();
        queue.enqueueNDRangeKernel(kernel, cl::NDRange{x, y}, cl::NDRange{end_x - x, end_y - y}, {}, nullptr, &events.back());
    }
}

queue.enqueueWaitForEvents(events);
```

Comment: Actually, I think your method is the better one. Mine is not acceptable because apparently, you cannot set the arguments of a kernel while it is running (see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25437554/clenqueuendrangekernel-blocks-execution). When I run my code, I don't get kernel overlap at all. I will try your method!

Comment: @Damian I think there's a misunderstanding from that post: You *can* set Kernel arguments while a kernel is running; those changes just can't affect any kernels already in the queue or already running: they can only affect kernels you haven't queued up yet. I'm quite certain I've written code similar to what you've written many times in the past. Especially since you're apparently using multiple Queues.

Comment: Huh, that's interesting. I'm runnning my kernels the way I described and they seem to execute sequentially. I have a for loop over setting the arguments and the kernel enqueueing. At the end, I have a for loop calling the `queue[i].flush()` and `queue[i].finish()` commands to wait untill all of them are done.

Comment: And should this work even if the kernel is the same for everything? Because I even tried creating multiple kernel objects (in a vector) and that didn't make a difference.

Comment: @Damian That's a different thing. Queues have to be explicitly instructed to allow "out of order execution" when they are created. The default OpenCL API behavior is for Queues to execute instructions in the order they're submitted. Review [1.0 API documentation](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/clCreateCommandQueue.html) or [2.0 API documentation](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/2.0/docs/man/xhtml/clCreateCommandQueueWithProperties.html) on Command Queue creation.

Comment: right. That's why I created K different in-order-queues in the same spirit as CUDA streams. Each queue is in order, so if I do a memory operation and launch a kernel in the same queue, they should be sequential, unless I have this all wrong.